# Best method to convert CSV file of lat/lon and depth data to bathymetry polygon?

Tags: convert, csv, contour, ascii, bathymetry

I'm trying to create bathymetry polygons based on lat/long and depth data. I have tried several methods and the resulting polygons are clunky.

Make XY Event Layer-->Copy Features--> Project--> 
Interpolate with IDW-->Make values Integeter with (Int tool) -->
Raster to Polygon
Dissolve Polygons by depth, so that all areas of equal depth are in same feature in the bathymetry feature class.

This method results as you might imagine is a clunky, blocky polygon. 
I have tried several routes, including Contour, Create Filled Contour - I'm sure there must be a simpler way to create a bathymetry polygon?

Comment: Is there an example ascii file to test with that is available?

Comment: ..sorry I'm  new here. how do I attach example file? thank you.

Comment: a hyperlink to a file is ideal, thanks, only images can be uploaded.

Comment: Not sure about the ASCII, but the Excel CSV I've worked with primarily is simply three columns, lat, lon, and depth. I'll edited the title to be more accurate to my question....

Comment: Do you have access to ArcGIS? Then GeoWizards will be the solution http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/convertPnt2Pl.htm and then http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_SolutionCenter/gw_create_contour_polygons.htm

Comment: I'm also not clear what you're trying to do, are the points described in your CSV file the vertices of the polygons you'd like to create, and you just need to connect the dots?

Comment: Thank you both for reaching out. The results so far have been to convert raster to contour, and attempt to use Snap (Editing)or Extend Line (Editing) to close up edges, before converting the contour to polygon. I am working on ArcGIS 10.1 with full Advanced license. It is difficult/time consuming to access external utilities such as GeoWizardsm though I appreciate that your suggestion is a potentially simpler solution.

Comment: Dan C, to clarify: I am ultimately attempting to create a bathymetry polygon. I had access to both a CSV file (lat,lon, depth data) for the region, as well as a raster of the bathymetry. Both of these options lead me to a contour, but are not easily converted to filled polygons. And, I have attempted to use "Filled Contours" tool which doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered creating a TIN? http://pubs.usgs.gov/sim/3112/